# why same request method has different html response structs?

Tags: python, selenium, request, python-requests

`python3.6` + `win10`

When I scraped the detail data page like `https://ipinfo.io/AS...`  from `https://ipinfo.io/countries/us`,  I got different result from requests module, sometimes the page resource was not complete.

As below, I put two examples:

```py
import requests
headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
}
```

(1) request page  `https://ipinfo.io/AS13489` (complete one)

```py
complete_result = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS13489', headers=headers)
print(complete_result.text)
```

result get complete html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

...    

</body>

</html>
```

(2) request page  `https://ipinfo.io/AS7018`(not complete one)

```py
not_complete_result = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS7018', headers=headers)
print(not_complete_result.text)
```

Result just get not complete html page:

```
 </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
...     
</body>

</html>
```

(3) besides `selenium`  didn't work in my attempts either:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS7018')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

print(browser.page_source)
```

Result not complete

```
            256

        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">  

...

</iframe>
</html>
```

Update my required data pic, my confusion now is that sometimes these part data disappear.

[image]

Missing part of html content:

[image]

update my codes:

```py
import re
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
}

# s = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS7018', headers=headers).text
# not work , s get a not complete html cntent.

s = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS13489', headers=headers).text

asn_code, name = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>',s).groups()

country = re.search(r'.*href="/countries.*">(?P<COUNTRY>.*)?</a>',s).group("COUNTRY")

registry = re.search(r'Registry.*?pb-md-1">(?P<REGISTRY>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("REGISTRY").strip()

ip = re.search(r'IP Addresses.*?pb-md-1">(?P<IP>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("IP").strip()


print(asn_code, name, country, registry, ip)
# AS13489 EPM Telecomunicaciones S.A. E.S.P. Colombia lacnic 3,137,536
```

Comment: Works fine for me... When I check *IP* `"80,925,184 " in not_complete_result.text` returns `True`, so it seem that required data is in page source

Comment: @Andersson, thank you sir, but the missed part I mean is above `<div>` part ,

Comment: Why don't you just use our ASN API? Sounds like it'd work better for you, and won't be against our ToS, which scraping is! :) See https://ipinfo.io/developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get required data as below:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
}
not_complete_result = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS7018', headers=headers)
source = html.fromstring(not_complete_result.text)

print(source.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "card-header")]/h3/text()[1]')[0])
#  'AS7018 AT&T Services, Inc.'
for item in source.xpath('(//div[contains(@class, "card-body")])[1]//div[contains(@class, "col-")]/p'):
    print(item.text_content().strip())
# att.com
# United States
# 1996-07-30
# arin
# 80,925,184
# isp
# There are 78,008 domain names hosted across 34,656 IP addresses on this ASN.
```

Comment: It's so kind that you give  your solution by xpath here , but what confusing me now  is why sometimes I cannot get complete page resource ...

Comment: @jiaJimmy , it depends on what you mean by *'complete page resource'*...

Comment: at first I  use regex to match my required data as above ,  `asn_code, name = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>',s).groups()` , the result supposed to be `AS7018` and `AT&T Services, Inc.` But sometimes this doesn't work because of I cannot get complete page resource by `not_complete_result.text`.

Comment: Besides, `"AS7018 AT&T Services, Inc." in not_complete_result.text` is `False`, it's wired  that you can find it by xpath.

Comment: @jiaJimmy 1) You should never use regex for parsing HTML! 2) In page source text appears as `"AS7018 AT&amp;T Services, Inc."`. Note that ampersand character. That's why `"AS7018 AT&T Services, Inc." in not_complete_result.text` is `False`

Comment: thanks for advice, but i think the problem now has nothing to do with regex, update my codes above, i want to know why sometimes it works howerver sometimes not.

Comment: @jiaJimmy it's not only about current case. Using regex for parsing HTML considered to be very bad practice and should not be used

Comment: I am  grateful  for that

Comment: But return to my question, why same request method has different html response structs?  `s1 = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS13489', headers=headers).text`, `s2 = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS7018', headers=headers).text`. I get different struct while printing

Comment: @jiaJimmy your request returns HTML document. It should NOT have the same structure for all similar sources. Also https://ipinfo.io/AS7018 contains bug (when page is opened the current tab is "Details" while it should be "Summary". And when you click "Summary" - both tabs appeared as selected)

Comment: But when i get text by `requests.get(url).text`, shouldn't it be like `<html><body>...</body></html>`, why i get `</tr>...</body></html>` instead?

Comment: @jiaJimmy `requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/AS7018', headers=headers).text` returns HTML with common markup. Not sure why you think it looks like `</tr>...</body></html>`...

Comment: Why don't you just use our (IPinfo's) ASN API? Sounds like it'd work better for you, and won't be against our ToS, which scraping is! :) See ipinfo.io/developers